# Unable to retrieve TinyMCE's content from a parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce

I have asked the question on their Github but no answer so far so I'm trying my luck here.

I'm creating a form that contains TinyMCE as component ; my goal is to be able to use and reuse this component through the whole website as the main Wysiwyg. I import it, give it a `v-model` and I'm good to go.

So, it "works", as in, I can set a value *via* the `v-model` and TinyMCE will display it nicely. However, it looks like I'm on a write only mode, because I can't extract the current data from it.

I originally created an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymcevue-forked-3vmvt) for the Github issue, you can see it here so that you have a good idea of what I'm facing. There's a textarea under the TinyMCE component that has the same v-model, just try to play with it and see the behavior.

While everything works if I declare a v-model inside the TinyMCE component, what do I need to do
get my value to the parent component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the reason for wrapping the editor in a custom component?  You can send values to a parent component using `$emit`

Comment: As said in my question, it's for reusability / DRY purpose, the configuration I want to use is a bit more complex than the example I provided, and I don't feel like copying / pasting it everywhere. Could you please provide an example of how I should use $emit? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `v-model` on the editor itself too or else it only receives the parent value but can't update it.  However, you can't use the prop `value` for that because props [can't be mutated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

Using a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) with `v-model` is a good solution here:

```html
<editor
  api-key="qagffr3pkuv17a8on1afax661irst1hbr4e6tbv888sz91jc"
  v-model="model"
></editor>
```

Leave the `value` prop as is and add the computed:

```js
computed: {
  model: {
    get() {
      return this.value;
    },
    set(val) {
      this.$emit('input', val);
    }
  }
}
```

The computed setter returns the prop when getting, but emits rather than setting it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I still can't get the value from the parent component, should I edit the parent component too?

Comment: No problem.  The only thing you need to do in the parent is populate `someArticle` with a starting value.  If you can't get that to work, post an updated sandbox and I'll try to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I updated my CodeSandbox with your answer and added some default text for the v-model, you can check if you want

Comment: I don't see any changes to https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymcevue-forked-3vmvt

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the url changed: https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymcevue-forked-9pbxw

Comment: The `Wysiwyg` template is still using `:value` instead of `v-model`

Comment: I forgot about that! Thanks a lot, it works like a charm now!!